# typing in an email body apparently I type some key that instantly sends the message

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

When I am typing in an email body apparently I type some key that instantly sends the email.  That is problematic for me instantly.  What am I doing that causes that?

Comment: Control-enter? (which is send in a few email clients).

Comment: [edit] to include your email client, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Wich client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac) is send in Outlook, Gmail and some other clients.

Maybe you're accidentally hitting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key or it's stuck down?

Comment: perhaps it is the control key; no it is not stuck down.  I use it often for other things.  I am using gmail and it is NOT a good thing to have it sent before I am ready to send.